# Promised recursive function does not trigger return statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to write a "slug validator" querying my database if the wanted slugged string is available.

For this I use un reccursive function that increments a number and test it concatenated with my slugged string.

Example :

- I want to insert `my-slugged-string` in my database. I want to check if
  `my-slugged-string` is available (not already used).
- I query my
  database with `my-slugged-string` and if it already exists, tries
  again with `my-slugged-string1`, and if it already exists tries again
  with `my-slugged-string2`, etc...
- If `my-slugged-stringx` does not exists, return this value.

First of all, here is my code

```
import nodeGremlin from 'gremlin';
import gremlin from 'gremlin-template-string';

import slug from 'slug';

import Promise from 'bluebird';


let client = nodeGremlin.createClient(8182, 'localhost');
client = Promise.promisifyAll(client);


module.exports.generateNew = function (label, stringToSlug) {
    let sluggedString = slug(stringToSlug, {lower: true});
    return findAvailable(label, sluggedString);
}

function findAvailable(label, stringToTest, i = ''){
    const mixedString = stringToTest + i;
    let query = `g.V().has(label, '${label}').has('slug', '${mixedString}')`;
    return client.executeAsync(query)
        .then((item) => {
            if (item[0]){
                if (i === '') i = 0;
                return findAvailable(label, stringToTest, ++i);
            }
            // breakpoint
            console.log(mixedString);
            return mixedString;

        })
        .catch((err) => {
            // manage error
        });
}
```

And i'm calling this code like this

```
import * as Slug from './slug';
import Promise from 'bluebird';

let slug = Promise.promisifyAll(Slug);

export function create(item = {}, callback) {
    // [...]
    slug.generateNewAsync('item', 'my string to slug and test')
        .then((sluggedstring)=>{
            //bla bla bla
        })
    // [...]
}
```

My problem is that, even if the breakpoint is reached (the algorithm works, I have already test it : I can `console.log` the right value), nothing will be returned and the process won't stop and keep runing for eeeveeer... until the timeout comes ! :) :) :)

I'm probably missing something on the javascript promises principle.

I'd appriciate your help guys ;)

EDIT : thanks to @Adam, code edited

Comment: in your `findAvailable` function you don't `return` with `client.executeAsync(query)...`

Comment: OMG what foolish mistake. But adding `return` with `client.executeAsync(query)...` does exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, nothing will be returned because there is no `return` statement in `findAvailable`! Add it here:

```
function findAvailable(label, stringToTest, i = ''){
    const mixedString = stringToTest + i;
    let query = `g.V().has(label, '${label}').has('slug', '${mixedString}')`;
    return client.executeAsync(query)
//  ^^^^^^
        .then(…);
}
```

That said, the module you've written will already return a promise now. There is no need to promisify it - in fact, it won't work with promisification as it doesn't take a callback. Don't call `promisifyAll` on it, don't use the `Async` suffix for the method call:

```
…
export function create(item = {}, callback) {
    …
    return slug.generateNew('item', 'my string to slug and test')
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^
        .then((sluggedstring)=>{
            … 
        });
}
```

Comment: This is what i 've just done, thanks to Adam. But the result is the same. return is not triggered.

Comment: WOW. This works !
http://data.whicdn.com/images/92550272/large.jpg
Can you tell me why ?